# "re-register" PHP session based on form POST

Tags: php, session, post

When a user logs in to my website, i create a session called `$_SESSION['session_city_id']` which collects an ID from MySQL

I wonder if it's possible to change the data it contains from a form. I have created the form `select_city` which looks like this:

```
<form name='select_city' action='sessions.php' method='post' style='display:inline;'>
  <select onchange='this.form.submit()'>
  <option value='1'>The first value</option>
  <option value='2'>The second value</option>
  <option value='3'>The third value</option>
  </select>
 <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>
```

My `sessions.php` looks like this (I just started programming in PHP so don't bash me for being a complete noob!)

```
<?php
session_start();
$url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //Find out where the user came from

if (isset($_POST['select_city'])){

    $_POST['select_city'] = $city_id;
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['session_city_id'])){
    unset($_SESSION['session_city_id']);
    }
    $_SESSION['session_city_id'] = $city_id;                
}
header ("Location: $url"); //Redirect back to the page the user came from
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just override you session variable with the new value (no need to unset)

```
if (isset($_POST['select_city'])){
    $_SESSION['session_city_id']=(int)$_POST['select_city']; // add a better check!
}
```

and don't forget the name in your field

```
<select name="select_city" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
```

Comment: was just about to suggest putting the name at the select tag instead at the form

Comment: Sorry, my fault, just edited after. It must be in the input attributes.

Comment: Thank you for the post. However I still get the old ID in the session variable...

Comment: Try print_r($_POST) and print_r($_SESSION) at the top of your script. Maybe a typo anywhere.

Comment: on the sessions.php file it outputs the correct ID, but not on the site i get redirected back to... Hmm. How is this possible? On the login.php i ask, is this a user - if so - create sessions and redirect to index.php. The index.php file is the site i get redirected back to after form submit.. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is the session id the same? Is the page cached in your browser? Try Ctrl + r!

Comment: No it's not, I tried ctrl+R already. The session (after form submission, and redirection) is still the initial one who is given after a succesful login. I'm pulling my hair out!

Comment: Is the value ($_SESSION['session_city_id']) in session.php correctly set? Try `echo $_SESSION['session_city_id']` before redirection.

Comment: Yes, it is set correctly. If I remove the redirection and echo out the "new" session, it outputs the correct ID from the form...

Comment: And `echo session_id()` is also the same on both pages?

Comment: It does not echo out a session_id on the sessions.php page.. Is this strange?

Comment: Can you please look after your session cookies? Did you specify another session name?

Comment: It work's now! I guess I should be ashamed because I had removed session_start(); ..... Duh! Thank's for your help though!

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_POST['select_city'])){
    $city_id = $_POST['select_city'];
    $_SESSION['session_city_id'] = $city_id;                
}
```

Do not need unset, and you replaced the assignment.

Comment: +1.  I would add an `intval()` around the assignment just to ensure that it is an integer.

Comment: It dosn't seem to work. When I get redirected back to the page I came from and echo out the session, it still outputs the "old" value.

Comment: shouldn't name='select_city' be at the select tag and not at the form? or is it just the same?

Comment: Oops, yes. He should set name for the select, not for the form.

Comment: I changed the name of the select tag and pasted your code but it still outputs the old ID when I get redirected back... Any ideas?

Comment: well A. you could be re initializing the value of id on that redirect age B. your form isn't submitting.